# How to call a controller action using Javascript $.get - Yii?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii

So, recently I've been trying to call a controller action via javascript `$.get`. I was suggested by a fellow Stack Overflow member to use

```
 $.get("custom/balance", function(){  });
```

Where custom is the name of the controller that I am using and balance is `actionBalance()`—a function that I have declared inside of that controller. I have tried to do so but it seems that the function is not being called. I have placed intentional errors inside of that function so I am sure it is not being called via the `$.get` function.

previously, I had directed `$.get` to a file in assets like so

```
$.get("assets/balance.php, function() {  });
```

This had worked perfectly.

Finally, here is the `actionBalance` that I have declared - is it possible that I need to then call that function? I'm not sure why custom/balance is not calling the action itself.

```
public function actionBalance() {

    // Return a string
    echo '7000';

}
```

Comment: Can you check if the mod_rewrite is actually being called via ajax and what really happens, maybe you need `/` before the controller name?

Comment: If you call "custom/balance" in your browser, do you get something ?

Comment: Controller name? Show `urlManager.rules`.

Comment: Royal BG - what do you mean by mod_rewrite?

Comment: Martial, If I call custom/balance in my browser I get "7000" 
Of course what I am actually calling is paypeople/index.php?r=account/balance

Comment: So, I changed the $.get to "index.php?r=account/balance" - and it works (i.e. returns 7000). But is this the wrong path? I feel like this is not how the path should be structured/there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for the previously incomplete answer which left you confused, as I assumed everyone would want to remove the index.php script name from the URL.

If you are using the default settings, yes, you should add the `index.php?r=` before the path. `index.php` is called the entry script in Yii. Other files are hidden/protected from the public in the protected folder.

To hide this entry script from the URL, please follow this tutorial on Yii's website:

- [Yii 1.1: Url: hide index.php](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/)